# pgfplots: Displaying a bar graph and a table from the same input file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I try to display on one Beamer slide a bar graph and a table with numbers taken from the same input file (to avoid repetition when copying the data). For now, I am stuck on this error message:

```
PGFPlots: reading {benchmarks.data}
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@setfontsize #1#2#3->\@nomath #1
                        \ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \let \@curr...
l.33 \end{frame}
```

My data file is the folllowing:

```
paradigm                                          position  time
{\scriptsize \shortstack{Procedural\\(append)}}     1       53
{\scriptsize \shortstack{Procedural\\(prepend)}}    2       64
{\scriptsize Object-Oriented}                       3       45
{\scriptsize Functional}                            4       44
{\scriptsize List Comprehension}                    5       30
```

And, here is a stripped down version of my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Benchmark Results}
  \begin{columns}[m]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
        \begin{axis}[%
          ybar, bar width=0.65cm,%
          xmin=0.5,xmax=5.5, xtick=data,%
          xticklabels from table={benchmarks.data}{paradigm},%
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east,inner sep=0mm},%
          ylabel={\Large Time (s)}, ylabel near ticks]
          \addplot table [x=position,y=time] {benchmarks.data};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}      
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.35\textwidth}
      \pgfplotstabletypesetfile[%
      every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor{blue!15}}},
      every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
      every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
      columns/paradigm/.style={column name={Paradigm}},
      columns/position/.style={column name={Position}},
      columns/time/.style={column name={Time (s)}}] {benchmarks.data}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The most strange things is that the bar chart is working well, but I cannot make the table compile properly.

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table automatically assumes numerical input but you have text in the `paradigm` column hence it needs `string type` indicator. Also you can prefix/append code to the cells by postprocessing options.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,colortbl,lmodern}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotstableread{
paradigm position time
{\shortstack{Procedural\\(append)}}     1       53
{\shortstack{Procedural\\(prepend)}}    2       64
{Object-Oriented}                       3       45
{Functional}                            4       44
{List Comprehension}                    5       30
}\mytable


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Benchmark Results}
  \begin{columns}[m]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
        \begin{axis}[%
          ybar, bar width=0.65cm,%
          xmin=0.5,xmax=5.5, xtick=data,%
          xticklabels from table={\mytable}{paradigm},%
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east,inner sep=0mm},%
          ylabel={\Large Time (s)}, ylabel near ticks]
          \addplot table [x=position,y=time] {\mytable};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}      
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \pgfplotstabletypesetfile[%
      every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor{blue!15}}},
      every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
      every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
      columns/paradigm/.style={
                     column name={Paradigm},
                     string type,
                     postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={\scriptsize}{}}
                    },
      columns/position/.style={column name={Position}},
      columns/time/.style={column name={Time (s)}}] {\mytable}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>Sorry for the inline data. I was kind of lazy to include the `filecontents` package.</sub>

Comment: Damn, it was really simple. Thanks a lot ! Now, I will try to get rid of this `position` column... :)

Comment: @perror You can start with the option `columns={paradigm,time}` in the table and remove the `position` column related options.

Comment: It worked as you said ! But, I am a bit surprised that you cannot get rid of this `position` column that I only use to set the x-position. Oh well, I'm fine with this anyway. Thanks !

Comment: @perror Oh now I get it you want to get rid of it from the table. You can use `x expr = \coordindex+1` instead of `x=position` to use the coordinate counter. It starts from 0 so I often add one to it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was definitely given by percusse, so if you vote for this answer, vote also for [percusse's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113389/pgfplots-displaying-a-bar-graph-and-a-table-from-the-same-input-file/113405#113405).

This answer is just here to provide the complete LaTeX code (and the final render) in order to gather all the tricks I did use (this may be useful to other people).

Anyway, if you see possible improvement, feel free to comment on it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{multirow, pgfplotstable,booktabs,colortbl,lmodern}

\pgfplotstableread{
paradigm        time2_7     time3_2
{Procedural (append)}   118.95      170.42
{Procedural (prepend)}  145.71      193.77
{Object-Oriented}        97.51      154.07
{Functional}             95.17      149.88
{List Comprehension}    106.26      162.37
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Benchmark Results}

  \vfill
  \begin{columns}[m]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.625]
        \begin{axis}[
          ybar, bar width=8pt,ymin=0,
          xmin=0.5,xmax=5.5, xtick=data,
          xticklabels from table={\mytable}{paradigm},
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east,inner sep=0mm},
          ylabel={\Large Time (s)}, ylabel near ticks]
          \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1,y=time2_7] {\mytable};
          \addlegendentry{Python 2.7};
          \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1,y=time3_2] {\mytable};
          \addlegendentry{Python 3.2};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}\scriptsize
      \pgfplotstabletypesetfile[
        columns={paradigm, time2_7, time3_2},
        every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor{blue!15}}},
        every head row/.style={
          before row={\toprule 
            \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Programming Paradigm} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Time (s)}\\ \cmidrule{2-3}},
          after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        columns/paradigm/.style={
          column name={},
          string type},
        columns/time2_7/.style={
          column name={Python 2.7},
          postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={}{\,s}}},
        columns/time3_2/.style={
          column name={Python 3.2},
          postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={}{\,s}}}] 
          {\mytable}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \vfill

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the final result is the following:

[image]

Comment: I had hard time to generate the PNG from the PDF with `convert`, do you use some specific settings or tool for this ?