# text size in pgfplotstable tables

Tags: fontsize, pgfplotstable

What's the easiest way to control the text size of all non-header cells of a column in a table created by `pgfplotstable`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, header=has colnames]{
test1,test2
1,2
3,4
}
\end{document}
```

So, for example, in this table, I want to change the size of `2` and `4`.

I tried playing with `.style={font=...}`, but got nowhere. Also, I found `columns/test2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={\scriptsize}{}}}` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113389/pgfplots-displaying-a-bar-graph-and-a-table-from-the-same-input-file), but I can't believe that is the easiest way.

Comment: Enclose your table code with `{\everymath{\scriptstyle} ..... }` which would make all the math scriptstyle by default. inside those braces. And by default pgfplotstable typesets columns with `$...$` around the content.

Comment: Unluckily, this doesn't work for text cells, and doesn't let me select only some columns, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Here is a repeatable setting way. Pgfkeys offers an iterating execution of keys via `/.list` handler. In english, it will execute the same style for every element in the list. Example, I've made added `\scriptsize` to the cells and made them string type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    my iterating settings/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/columns/#1/.style={
            string type,
            postproc cell content/.style={
                 @cell content/.add={\scriptsize}{}
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[my iterating settings/.list={test1,test2,test3,test4}]{
test1 test2 test3 test4
1     2     6     8
3     4     7     9
c     u     b     e
c     a     k     e
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Too tired to enter the column names, want an easier solution? We still love you. You can use the column number index for ease of access since `pgfplotstable` supports `display columns/<col no>` syntax. Example, I want some columns bold and `\footnotesize` (I don't know why).

Notice that I have shifted the `string type` out to the general setting to apply to all columns because our iterating list doesn't touch each column but all has text in them. And column numbers start from zero.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    my num iterating settings/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={
            postproc cell content/.style={
                 @cell content/.add={\footnotesize\bfseries}{}
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\hspace{-5cm}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
    my num iterating settings/.list={0,1,...,4,8,10,...,15}
    ]{
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10 test11 test12 test13 test14 test15 test16
1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8        1     2     6     8
3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9        3     4     7     9
c     u     b     e     c     u     b     e     c     u     b     e        c     u     b     e
c     a     k     e     c     a     k     e     c     a     k     e        c     a     k     e
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I might have copy-pasted a little too much...